# ¿Como transformar un archivo unicode con caracteres especiales a algo legible?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, unicode, codificacion

Tengo un archivo javascript que básicamente es un diccionario pero no entiendo porque los caracteres especiales no aparecen, quiero transformarlo a algo legible para poder usarlo y no hacer eso de forma manual.

Esto es parte del archivo:

```js
var lang = new Array();
lang['cuentamos_acerca_de_ti']='Tu cuenta:';
lang['cuentamos_acerca_de_tu_club_asociacion']='H�blanos de tu club o asociaci�n:';
lang['re_ingresa_tus_datos']='Confirma tus datos para continuar';
lang['elija_su_ubicacion_en_el_mapa']='Ubica tu club o asociaci�n en el mapa.';
lang['mejora_tu_ubicacion']='No hemos detectado tu ciudad o tu provincia o pa�s. Por favor mejora tu ubicaci�n.';
lang['completa_datos']='Completa el formulario para registrar tu club o asociaci�n.';
```

Lo pase al bloc de notas y lo intenté guardar como formato utf-8 pero no funcionó. también intenté guardarlo en el formato ANSI y me lanzó una advertencia diciendo que el archivo contenía caracteres en formato UNICODE, asi que vi como transformar de UNICODE a UTF-8 pero no me funciona. como puedo hacer para que en vez de 'H?blanos' aparezca 'Háblanos' y asi sucesivamente? gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: Unicode es la codificación, utf8 es un formato. No transformas de Unicode de a utf8. Es posible que tu fichero esté en Unicode pero usando UTF 16 (otro formato para guardar Unicode), por ejemplo

Comment: Por otro lado es habitual que Windows use su propia codificación, windows-1252.

Comment: Es posible transformarlo los caracteres especiales al caracter correcto ? es un archivo muy grande y ando buscando una forma para hacerlo automatico.

Comment: ¿Si lo abres con el bloc de notas, se ve bien?

Comment: Se ve igual, no cambia en nada.